# pandas pivot table on predefined values

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I am trying to count values for multiple columns including values that might not occur in the column.
Given example data frame:

```
foo = pd.DataFrame({'A':[False,False,True], 'B':[None, False, True], 'C': [None, None, None]})
```

my final result would look like:

[image]

`.value_counts()` would not work here for me since it will miss some values plus it works primary on pd.Series. So far I tried pivot table but without success:

```
# returns KeyError: False
foo.pivot_table(index=[False, True, None], columns=foo.columns, aggfunc='count')
```

How can pandas count all occurrences for specified values in multiple columns ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) and [`crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html):

```
bar = foo.melt(var_name='pivot_values').replace({None: 'None'})
# for some reason, even using "dropna=False" in crosstab still removes None

out = (pd.crosstab(bar['pivot_values'], bar['variable'], dropna=False)
         .reset_index().rename_axis(columns=None)
      )
```

Output:

```
  pivot_values  A  B  C
0        False  2  1  0
1         True  1  1  0
2         None  0  1  3
```

Comment: thank you ! it almost solved it. I had to change `bar['variable']` to `bar['value']` and after that the dataframe was transposed. so `df = out.transpose()` and `df.rename(columns=df.iloc[0]).reset_index().rename(columns={'index':'pivot_values'}).iloc[1:,:]`